# Alinear div horizontalmente?

Tags: html, css, div

Tengo el siguiente codigo html y css:

```css
#formulario_alta {
    margin-top: 5%;
    //  display:inline-block;
  
}




.contenedorNombreClub, .contenedorCIF, .contenedorDireccionClub, .contenedorPoblacionClub, .contenedorCodigoPostal, .contenedorServicio, .contenedorNombreBanco, .contenedorCodigoPostalBanco, .contenedorCuentaBancaria,
.contenedorNombreRepresentante,.contenedorApellidosRepresentante,.contenedorDNI,.contenedorFechaNacimiento,.contenedorCargoClub,.contenedorEmailRepresentante,.contenedorDireccionDomicilio,
.contenedorLocalidadDomicilio,.contenedorCodigoPostalRepresentante
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#formulario_alta .etiquetaNombreClub, #formulario_alta .etiquetaCIF, #formulario_alta .etiquetaDireccionClub, #formulario_alta .etiquetaPoblacionClub, #formulario_alta .etiquetaCodigoPostal, #formulario_alta .etiquetaServicio,
#formulario_alta .etiquetaNombreBanco, #formulario_alta .etiquetaCodigoPostalBanco, #formulario_alta .etiquetaCuentaBancaria,
#formulario_alta .etiquetaNombreRepresentante, #formulario_alta .etiquetaApellidosRepresentante, #formulario_alta .etiquetaDNI, #formulario_alta .etiquetaFechaNacimiento, #formulario_alta .etiquetaCargoClub,
#formulario_alta .etiquetaEmailRepresentante, #formulario_alta .etiquetaDireccionDomicilio, #formulario_alta .etiquetaLocalidadDomicilio,
#formulario_alta .etiquetaCodigoPostalRepresentante label {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.valorNombreClub, .valorCIF, .valorDireccionClub, .valorPoblacionClub, .valorCodigoPostal, .valorServicio, .valorNombreBanco, .valorCodigoPostalBanco, .valorCuentaBancaria,
.valorNombreRepresentante, .valorApellidosRepresentante, .valorDNI, .valorFechaNacimiento, .valorCargoClub, .valorEmailRepresentante, .valorDireccionDomicilio, .valorLocalidadDomicilio, .valorCodigoPostalRepresentante {
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-family: inherit;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div id="formulario_alta">
 <div id="formulario_club">
  <div class="contenedorNombreClub">
   <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaNombreClub">Nombre del Club*</span><br><input name="NombreClub" type="text" id="NombreClub" class="cajaTexto valorNombreClub">
  </div><div class="contenedorCIF">
   <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaCIF">CIF del Club*</span><br><input name="CIF" type="text" id="CIF" class="cajaTexto valorCIF">
  </div><div class="contenedorDireccionClub">
   <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaDireccionClub">Dirección Domicilio*</span><br><input name="DireccionClub" type="text" id="DireccionClub" class="cajaTexto valorDireccionClub">
  </div><div class="contenedorPoblacionClub">
   <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaPoblacionClub">Población*</span><br><input name="PoblacionClub" type="text" id="PoblacionClub" class="cajaTexto valorPoblacionClub">
  </div><div class="contenedorCodigoPostal">
   <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaCodigoPostal">Código postal*</span><br><input name="CodigoPostal" type="text" id="CodigoPostal" class="cajaTexto valorCodigoPostal">
  </div>
 </div><div id="formulario_contrato">
  <div class="contenedorServicio">
   <span class="etiquetaFormulario"> Plan*</span><br><select name="Servicio" id="Servicio" class="cajaTexto valorServicio">
    <option value="Free">Free</option>
    <option value="Basico">Basico</option>
    <option value="Premium">Premium</option>

   </select>
  </div>
 </div><div id="formulario_banco">
  <div class="contenedorNombreBanco">
   <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaNombreBanco">Nombre del Banco*</span><br><input name="NombreBanco" type="text" id="NombreBanco" class="cajaTexto valorNombreBanco">
  </div><div class="contenedorCodigoPostalBanco">
   <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaCodigoPostalBanco">Código postal*</span><br><input name="CodigoPostalBanco" type="text" id="CodigoPostalBanco" class="cajaTexto valorCodigoPostalBanco">
  </div><div class="contenedorCuentaBancaria">
   <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaCuentaBancaria">Número de cuenta bancaria</span><br><input name="CuentaBancaria" type="text" id="CuentaBancaria" class="cajaTexto valorCuentaBancaria">
  </div>
 </div><div id="formulario_representante">
  <div class="contenedorNombreRepresentante">
   <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaNombreRepresentante">Nombre*</span><br><input name="NombreRepresentante" type="text" id="NombreRepresentante" class="cajaTexto valorNombreRepresentante">
  </div><div class="contenedorApellidosRepresentante">
   <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaApellidosRepresentante">Apellidos*</span><br><input name="ApellidosRepresentante" type="text" id="ApellidosRepresentante" class="cajaTexto valorApellidosRepresentante">
  </div><div class="contenedorDNI">
   <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaDNI">DNI / NIE*</span><br><input name="DNI" type="text" id="DNI" class="cajaTexto valorDNI">
  </div><div class="contenedorFechaNacimiento">
   <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaFechaNacimiento">Fecha de nacimiento*</span><br><input name="FechaNacimiento" type="text" id="FechaNacimiento" class="cajaTexto valorFechaNacimiento">
  </div><div class="contenedorCargoClub">
   <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaCargoClub">Cargo en el Club*</span><br><input name="CargoClub" type="text" id="CargoClub" class="cajaTexto valorCargoClub">
  </div><div class="contenedorEmailRepresentante">
   <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaEmailRepresentante">Correo electrónico*</span><br><input name="EmailRepresentante" type="text" id="EmailRepresentante" class="cajaTexto valorEmailRepresentante">
  </div><div class="contenedorDireccionDomicilio">
   <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaDireccionDomicilio">Dirección del Domicilio*</span><br><input name="DireccionDomicilio" type="text" id="DireccionDomicilio" class="cajaTexto valorDireccionDomicilio">
  </div><div class="contenedorLocalidadDomicilio">
   <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaLocalidadDomicilio">Localidad del Domicilio*</span><br><input name="LocalidadDomicilio" type="text" id="LocalidadDomicilio" class="cajaTexto valorLocalidadDomicilio">
  </div><div class="contenedorCodigoPostalRepresentante">
   <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaCodigoPostalRepresentante">Código postal*</span><br><input name="CodigoPostalRepresentante" type="text" id="CodigoPostalRepresentante" class="cajaTexto valorCodigoPostalRepresentante">
  </div>
 </div><div class="contenedorCheck">
  <input name="Check" type="checkbox" id="Check" class="checkSeleccion valorCheck"><label for="Check">Usted consiente, <strong>a través de la marcación de la presente casilla</strong>, al tratamiento de sus datos con las finalidades descritas en la <a href="http://localhost:8441/politica-privacidad">Política de Privacidad.</a></label>
 </div><div class="contenedoru800-17">
  <input type="submit" name="u800-17" value="Enviar" onclick="return EnviaFormulario('formularioAlta',['txt||NombreClub','txt||CIF','txt||DireccionClub','txt||PoblacionClub','txt||CodigoPostal','sel||Servicio','txt||NombreBanco','txt||CodigoPostalBanco','txt||NombreRepresentante','txt||ApellidosRepresentante','txt||DNI','txt||FechaNacimiento','txt||CargoClub','eml||EmailRepresentante','txt||DireccionDomicilio','txt||LocalidadDomicilio','txt||CodigoPostalRepresentante','check||Check']);" id="u800-17" class="valoru800-17">
 </div>
</div>
```

Me gustaría poder alinear el div formulario_representante a la derecha, pero arriba del todo (esto último no consigo hacerlo) junto al botón y al check. Como podria hacerlo de tal forma que quede correctamente alineado?

Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Deberías dejar la parte importante del código aquí, un link se puede perder o dejar de ser válido muy fácilmente y eso haría difícil a gente con el mismo o similar problema poder identificar que una respuesta podría ayudarle

Comment: Creo que tienes demasiadas clases Un elemento HTML puede tener varias clases así que lo que haría cambiaría todas las clases de tipo  `contenedorNombreClub` en `contenedor NombreClub`. Esto simplificaría mucho el css. Para poder alinear el `formulario_representante` a la derecha envolvería los previos contenedores en un div. Una vez que lo tengas hay muchos métodos de hacerlo: flotando cajas, utilizando flexbox etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba utilizando un grid de 2 columnas, el codigo quedaria asi:

```css
#formulario_alta {
    margin-top: 5%;
    /* display:inline-block;*/  
}

.contenedorNombreClub, .contenedorCIF, .contenedorDireccionClub, .contenedorPoblacionClub, .contenedorCodigoPostal, .contenedorServicio, .contenedorNombreBanco, .contenedorCodigoPostalBanco, .contenedorCuentaBancaria,
.contenedorNombreRepresentante,.contenedorApellidosRepresentante,.contenedorDNI,.contenedorFechaNacimiento,.contenedorCargoClub,.contenedorEmailRepresentante,.contenedorDireccionDomicilio,
.contenedorLocalidadDomicilio,.contenedorCodigoPostalRepresentante
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#formulario_alta{display: grid;grid-template-columns:50% 50%;grid-template-rows: auto auto auto; }
#formulario_alta>div[id^='formulario']{grid-column: 1;}
#formulario_alta>div[id*='representante']{grid-column: 2;grid-row: 1/span 3;}
#formulario_alta>div[class^='contenedor']{grid-column: 1/span 2;}

#formulario_alta .etiquetaNombreClub, #formulario_alta .etiquetaCIF, #formulario_alta .etiquetaDireccionClub, #formulario_alta .etiquetaPoblacionClub, #formulario_alta .etiquetaCodigoPostal, #formulario_alta .etiquetaServicio,
#formulario_alta .etiquetaNombreBanco, #formulario_alta .etiquetaCodigoPostalBanco, #formulario_alta .etiquetaCuentaBancaria,
#formulario_alta .etiquetaNombreRepresentante, #formulario_alta .etiquetaApellidosRepresentante, #formulario_alta .etiquetaDNI, #formulario_alta .etiquetaFechaNacimiento, #formulario_alta .etiquetaCargoClub,
#formulario_alta .etiquetaEmailRepresentante, #formulario_alta .etiquetaDireccionDomicilio, #formulario_alta .etiquetaLocalidadDomicilio,
#formulario_alta .etiquetaCodigoPostalRepresentante label {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.valorNombreClub, .valorCIF, .valorDireccionClub, .valorPoblacionClub, .valorCodigoPostal, .valorServicio, .valorNombreBanco, .valorCodigoPostalBanco, .valorCuentaBancaria,
.valorNombreRepresentante, .valorApellidosRepresentante, .valorDNI, .valorFechaNacimiento, .valorCargoClub, .valorEmailRepresentante, .valorDireccionDomicilio, .valorLocalidadDomicilio, .valorCodigoPostalRepresentante {
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-family: inherit;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
    <div id="formulario_alta">
        <div id="formulario_club">
            <div class="contenedorNombreClub">
                <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaNombreClub">Nombre del Club*</span><br><input name="NombreClub"
                    type="text" id="NombreClub" class="cajaTexto valorNombreClub">
            </div>
            <div class="contenedorCIF">
                <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaCIF">CIF del Club*</span><br><input name="CIF" type="text"
                    id="CIF" class="cajaTexto valorCIF">
            </div>
            <div class="contenedorDireccionClub">
                <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaDireccionClub">Dirección Domicilio*</span><br><input
                    name="DireccionClub" type="text" id="DireccionClub" class="cajaTexto valorDireccionClub">
            </div>
            <div class="contenedorPoblacionClub">
                <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaPoblacionClub">Población*</span><br><input name="PoblacionClub"
                    type="text" id="PoblacionClub" class="cajaTexto valorPoblacionClub">
            </div>
            <div class="contenedorCodigoPostal">
                <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaCodigoPostal">Código postal*</span><br><input
                    name="CodigoPostal" type="text" id="CodigoPostal" class="cajaTexto valorCodigoPostal">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="formulario_contrato">
            <div class="contenedorServicio">
                <span class="etiquetaFormulario"> Plan*</span><br><select name="Servicio" id="Servicio"
                    class="cajaTexto valorServicio">
                    <option value="Free">Free</option>
                    <option value="Basico">Basico</option>
                    <option value="Premium">Premium</option>

                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="formulario_banco">
            <div class="contenedorNombreBanco">
                <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaNombreBanco">Nombre del Banco*</span><br><input
                    name="NombreBanco" type="text" id="NombreBanco" class="cajaTexto valorNombreBanco">
            </div>
            <div class="contenedorCodigoPostalBanco">
                <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaCodigoPostalBanco">Código postal*</span><br><input
                    name="CodigoPostalBanco" type="text" id="CodigoPostalBanco"
                    class="cajaTexto valorCodigoPostalBanco">
            </div>
            <div class="contenedorCuentaBancaria">
                <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaCuentaBancaria">Número de cuenta bancaria</span><br><input
                    name="CuentaBancaria" type="text" id="CuentaBancaria" class="cajaTexto valorCuentaBancaria">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="formulario_representante">
            <div class="contenedorNombreRepresentante">
                <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaNombreRepresentante">Nombre*</span><br><input
                    name="NombreRepresentante" type="text" id="NombreRepresentante"
                    class="cajaTexto valorNombreRepresentante">
            </div>
            <div class="contenedorApellidosRepresentante">
                <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaApellidosRepresentante">Apellidos*</span><br><input
                    name="ApellidosRepresentante" type="text" id="ApellidosRepresentante"
                    class="cajaTexto valorApellidosRepresentante">
            </div>
            <div class="contenedorDNI">
                <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaDNI">DNI / NIE*</span><br><input name="DNI" type="text" id="DNI"
                    class="cajaTexto valorDNI">
            </div>
            <div class="contenedorFechaNacimiento">
                <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaFechaNacimiento">Fecha de nacimiento*</span><br><input
                    name="FechaNacimiento" type="text" id="FechaNacimiento" class="cajaTexto valorFechaNacimiento">
            </div>
            <div class="contenedorCargoClub">
                <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaCargoClub">Cargo en el Club*</span><br><input name="CargoClub"
                    type="text" id="CargoClub" class="cajaTexto valorCargoClub">
            </div>
            <div class="contenedorEmailRepresentante">
                <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaEmailRepresentante">Correo electrónico*</span><br><input
                    name="EmailRepresentante" type="text" id="EmailRepresentante"
                    class="cajaTexto valorEmailRepresentante">
            </div>
            <div class="contenedorDireccionDomicilio">
                <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaDireccionDomicilio">Dirección del Domicilio*</span><br><input
                    name="DireccionDomicilio" type="text" id="DireccionDomicilio"
                    class="cajaTexto valorDireccionDomicilio">
            </div>
            <div class="contenedorLocalidadDomicilio">
                <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaLocalidadDomicilio">Localidad del Domicilio*</span><br><input
                    name="LocalidadDomicilio" type="text" id="LocalidadDomicilio"
                    class="cajaTexto valorLocalidadDomicilio">
            </div>
            <div class="contenedorCodigoPostalRepresentante">
                <span class="etiquetaFormulario etiquetaCodigoPostalRepresentante">Código postal*</span><br><input
                    name="CodigoPostalRepresentante" type="text" id="CodigoPostalRepresentante"
                    class="cajaTexto valorCodigoPostalRepresentante">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contenedorCheck">
            <input name="Check" type="checkbox" id="Check" class="checkSeleccion valorCheck"><label for="Check">Usted
                consiente, <strong>a través de la marcación de la presente casilla</strong>, al tratamiento de sus datos
                con las finalidades descritas en la <a href="http://localhost:8441/politica-privacidad">Política de
                    Privacidad.</a></label>
        </div>
        <div class="contenedoru800-17">
            <input type="submit" name="u800-17" value="Enviar"
                onclick="return EnviaFormulario('formularioAlta',['txt||NombreClub','txt||CIF','txt||DireccionClub','txt||PoblacionClub','txt||CodigoPostal','sel||Servicio','txt||NombreBanco','txt||CodigoPostalBanco','txt||NombreRepresentante','txt||ApellidosRepresentante','txt||DNI','txt||FechaNacimiento','txt||CargoClub','eml||EmailRepresentante','txt||DireccionDomicilio','txt||LocalidadDomicilio','txt||CodigoPostalRepresentante','check||Check']);"
                id="u800-17" class="valoru800-17">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Ya intentaste con:

display: block;
margin: auto;

en el div?

Comment: Esto parece relamente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]